# Aus Klängen zusammengesetzte Wörter

Tags: vocabulary, compound, phonetics, curiosity

Man kann manche Wörter bilden, indem man sie aus den Klängen anderer Wörter zusammensetzt. Hier ein paar Beispiele:

- *Kreuz* + *Zunge* → *Kreuzung*
- *Prinz* + *Essen* → *Prinzessin*
- *Uhr* + *Laub* → *Urlaub*

Dass der zusammengesetzte Klang nicht *exakt* dem Klang des neuen Worts entspricht oder dass die Rechtschreibung des neuen Worts nicht genau stimmt, ist hier nicht weiter wichtig. Es gelten allerdings die folgenden Voraussetzungen:

Das Zielwort...

- ...hat zwei oder mehr Silben
- ...klingt fast genauso wie die beiden anderen Wörter, wenn man sie nacheinander ausspricht
- ...ist selbst kein [Kompositum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)) (*Sonnenblume* würde also z. B. nicht zählen)

Gibt es einen Fachbegriff für Wörter, die auf diese Art und Weise gebildet werden können und mithilfe dessen man weitere dieser Wörter nachschlagen kann?
Und gibt es eine Liste von ihnen, oder vielleicht sogar eine Regel, mit der man diese Wörter mechanisch erstellen kann?

Einen Anwärter für eine "Regel" habe ich bereits, aber bin mit ihr noch nicht zufrieden, da sie sehr begrenzt ist. Ich teile sie hier mal zur Vollständigkeit: Wenn das Zielwort mit *er* aufhört, dann muss man sich zumindest keine Gedanken mehr über die letzte Silbe machen, da viele Worte mit *er* aufhören, wie z. B. *Alt* + *Er* → *Alter*, *Mauer* + *Er* → *Maurer*, *Druck* + *Er* → *Drucker*, etc. Aber eine wirklich gute Regel wäre natürlich nicht darauf begrenzt, dass das Zielwort mit *er* aufhört, da vermutlich nur ein kleiner Bruchteil all dieser Wörter mit *er* aufhören.

Comment: "Tramper + Olivenöl  = Trampolin" zählt das auch?

Comment: @rastafile Ich denke nein, da das Wort *Olivenöl* darin nicht genug vorkommt (weder schriftlich noch klanglich).

Comment: Trampolin — klingt wie eine alte Benzinmarke mit speziellen Additiven für Fahrgemeinschaften.

Comment: Wie heißt das Reh mit Vornamen?

Comment: Mein Name ist Reh, Bus Reh. Oder war's umgekehrt?

Comment: @Janka Deshalb wollte ich auch die Regeln ausloten. Ich hatte auch "Vaseline" im Ohr. Moment: `Geselle + Ofen = Xylophon` - langsam gefällt mir das Spiel - radikaler Phonetismus.

Comment: @rastafile Meine Bemerkung "Wie heißt das Reh mit Vornamen?" sollte nicht witzig sein, vielmehr fand ich die Websuche danach recht ergiebig.

Comment: hmm ich hatte das "Kartoffelpü-" nicht auf dem Schirm. Muss wohl ein alter (flacher) Witz sein. Den gibt es im Land des Härdöpfelstocks weniger (Erd- oder Herd-, doch egal). Reh-Bus wie Rebus ist ja auch eher tiefsinnig als witzig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rebus-Prinzip** scheint das linguistische Fachwort zu sein, wie ja auch für die Rätsel in Zeitungen (vgl. Klee-Opa-Tra von mach; mit Bildern: Rebus)

Mir war, dass die ägyptischen Hieroglyphen auch auf beide Weisen verwendet wurden. Wikipedia nennt auf Englisch dies klar das *rebus principle*:

Die Entenfigur bedeutet Ente, kann aber auch nur für ihren Anfangsbuchstaben (oder -silbe?) "S-" stehen und so Teil eines neuen Wortes werden, das nichts mit Wasservögeln zu tun hat.

Und ich könnte auch noch bessere Beispiele bringen :-)

---

Ob Bilderrätsel, Hieroglyphen oder diese neue Variante (ich bin da etwas skeptisch bezüglich den Details): Es geht darum, es **rein phonetsch**  zu betrachten, mit einem Korn Salz. Viele Rebusse geben ja Hinweise, welche Buchstaben hinzuzufügen oder wegzulassen sind. (wobei da sogar das Wort verändert wird - aus einem Auge wird leicht "Lug" und mit einem "Pf-" von einem halben Pfau erhält man "Pflug", und man denkt: Wieso reicht ein "L" für ein "A" um aus einem Pfauenauge einen Pflug zu machen?)

Nach "Trampolin" hier noch ein richitger Vorschlag:

```
Schnecke  = Schnee + Ecke

Wagen     = Waage + Gen
Sakristei = Sack + Rist + Ei
```

Ich glaube maschinell geht das nicht gut. Es lebt von der semantischen Überraschung und der frechen Unterschlagung zweier "E". (mit der richtigen Software wohl schon, und dann durchsichten)

(Das mit "der Wagen" hat den Beiklang "etwas wagen")

("Sakristei" wird auch erstaunlich anatomisch)

---

Also da hat doch sicher schon jemand etwas *Kreatives* mit gemacht. Im Alltag wird das oft gemacht, von so dekonstruktivistischen (puh) Spassvögeln:

> "Sch-, ich habe keine Zigaretten mehr!"
>   "Dann nimm halt eine
>   Stossgarette"

(Zigarette = Zieh-Garette. Garette=(Stoss-)karre)

So gemein kann Sparache sein!

---

Wikipedia hat eine sehr schöne Abbildung von Alexanders (dem Grossen seinen) Namen auf Ägyptisch.

`AlksIndrs` (für Alexandros) war offenbar die phonetische Vorgabe. Es war ja beileibe nicht der erste und letzte Name, der in die eine oder ander Richtung übernommen/übersetzt wurde.

```
A l I n
  k   d  
  s   r
      s
```

Dabei ist das A und I so gross wie die beiden Konsonantenstapel. Das A ist zufälligerweise ein A-dler, von der Seite, der ein fast perfektes "A" bildet. Das "I" ist eine lange gerade Feder - wie ein lateinisches "I" (oder Isis-Feder?).

Das "l" schient ein Lüwe zu sein, das "n" wird durch Wellenline (also "Nil", den haben die ja so genannt). Also ergibt sich:

```
Alexander = Adler + Löwe (+Konsonanten) + Isis(?) + Nil (+Konsonanten)
```

als eigentliches Marketing-Logo. Das "-ex-" geht dabei ziemlich unter.

Das mit der Isis-Feder wird wohl gut erfunden sein (von mir), aber das ändert nicht viel.

Eigentlich wollte ich mit:

```
Geselle + Ofen = Xylophon
```

darauf hinweisen, dass man durchaus feine Regeln finden kann und muss. "Geselle" wird oft als "G'sell'" gesprochen (v.a. Dialekt). Also hat man schon "Gsell" -> "Xel". Dann Isisfeder spezial = "Y" --> "Xyl-".

Mit "Ofen": da muss man nur das unbetonte "e" als "o" wiederbeleben. Und wie aus "Gs-" "X" wurde, wird aus "f" "ph".

Man kann da Phonetisches und Semantisches kombinieren, so dass mehr als Wortspiele herauskkommen. Vielleicht ist es dann einfach Lyrik? Un-flache Wortspiele?

---

"PLANETT ERDE"

wäre doch ein gutes Graffiti; wird von Google gleich korrigiert (versteht noch weniger als keinen Spass).

Comment: Na sag ich's doch, da war jemand 2016 schneller: `+++ Sack, Rist, Ei: Katholischer Fußballtrainer prüft Ministranten-Elf in Kirchennebenraum gründlich +++`

Comment: Ja, ich denke, das Ganze kann als Rebus-Prinzip ohne Komposita verstanden werden.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne keine spezielle Bezeichnung für solche Wörter. Im Französischen gibt es ein verbreitetes Wortspiel, das auf ihnen beruht, nämlich die [Charade](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charade). Im Deutschen ist dieses Wortspiel unbekannt, was wohl daran liegt, dass die deutsche Silbenstruktur ein solches Spiel praktisch ausschliesst.

Typische deutsche Wörter bestehen aus einer stark betonten Hauptsilbe und schwach betonten Nebensilben. Für die Hauptsilbe gibt nur selten Synonyme, und die unbetonten Nebensilben können nicht als eigenständige Wörter auftreten. Also sind Wörter wie «Urlaub», die eine *Charade* erlauben würden, im Deutschen extrem selten. Im Französischen hingegen sind sie äusserst zahlreich.

Das einzige mir bekannte Beispiel einer *Charade* im Deutschen ist eben gerade eine Übersetzung aus dem Französischen, nämlich die *Charade* der Gladiatoren in *Asterix als Gladiator,* die ungefähr wie folgt geht (ich paraphrasiere aus der Erinnerung):

- Mein Erstes wächst auf der Wiese.
- Mein Zweites ist mein Grossvater.
- Mein drittes kommt aus der Trompete.
- Mein Ganzes ist Cäsars Liebe.

Antwort: *Kleopatra* (Klee – Opa – tra)

Ich glaube mich entfernt daran zu erinnern, dass ich als Kind überhaupt nicht verstand, was für ein merkwürdiges Spiel die Gladiatoren da denn spielten. Kein Wunder, ist dieses Spiel im Deutschen ja gar nicht bekannt.

Comment: Im Deutschen ist die Scharade eher ein pantomimisches oder graphisches Spiel, das stimmt schon (man denke an das Bekannte [Montagsmaler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI6mqIYe5Uc)). Aber es gibt solche ähnlichen [Rätsel im Deutschen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scharade_(Silbenr%C3%A4tsel)) durchaus auch in der hier dargestellten [Versform](https://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Gedichte/Neumann-Raetseldichtungen.htm).

Comment: Der Grund, warum dieses Spiel im Deutschen nicht gut funktioniert, im Gegensatz zum Französischen, ist die Tatsache, dass es im Französischen sehr viele Homophone gibt, im Gegensatz zum Deutschen.

Answer (score 1):

Dazu kann man etwas im Artikel [eggcorn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) der den englisch-sprachigen Neologismus einfach übernimmt, abgeleitet aus *acorn* "Eichel" =!= *egg* + *corn*). Diese sind zwar "semantically motivated".

Dagegen wäre für bspw. *?Uhr-Laub* eine Motivation noch zu suchen.

Es handelte sich dann also allenfalls um ein besonders flache Wortspiele. So stellt der Wikipedia-Artikel die Abgrenzung zum [Malapropismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaprolismus) klar, der eben keinen Sinn mehr ergeben muss, dessen Bezeichnung ebenfalls aus dem Englischen übernommen wurde, abgeleitet von einer erfundenen Figur, Frau Malaprop. Die Ausdrücke, die der Frau in den Mund gelegt werden, sind also im endeffekt absichtlich unstimmig.

Ansonsten könnte man sich nur schlecht darüber streiten, was wirklich als unsinnvoll zu gelten hätte und was nicht. Schließlich wäre *mal* (Französisch "schlecht") + *approp-* (etwa *to appropriate* "aneignen" oder *appropriate* "geeignet" oder auch *a-pro-pos*) durchaus divers interpretierbar.

---

Im wesentlichen folgen diese aus falscher Segmentierung und zumeist gezwungener oder unwillkürlicher Entfremdung der Lautwerte, oft von Fremdworten.

Comment: Ein Klassiker von Ehrhardt: https://www.pathologie-moers.de/sinne/imurwald.htm ... allerdings mit "Ur" statt "Uhr".

Comment: Den Eintrag gibt es auch in der [deutschsprachigen Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke nicht, dass es dafür ein eigenes Wort gibt. Persönlich würde ich dies jedoch als "kreativ"

> zusammengesetzte (freie) Morpheme, die ein neues [homophones](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophon) (freies) Morphem (oder Wort) bilden

bzw.

> homophone Morphem-[Komposition](https://home.zhaw.ch/pdan/ML/PROTOKOLLE/PROTOKOLL_I_3_2_03_GNACH.htm)

bezeichnen.

Ein [Morphem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphem) ist allgemein

> ein Fachausdruck der Linguistik für die kleinste Spracheinheit, die eine konstante Bedeutung oder grammatische Funktion hat.

Das [freie Morphem](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/freies_Morphem/) ist ein Morphem,

> das als selbständiges Wort vorkommt.

Also Wörter wie: Hut, Tisch, für, der, mein, groß.

Dies passt allerdings nur so lange wie man sich auf einfache Wörter beschränkt, die auch keine grammatischen Flexionsformen nutzen. So besteht z.B. [Kindergarten](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/lexikalisches_Morphem/) aus den (freien + lexikalischen) Morphemen Kind sowie -garten und dem grammatischen Morphem -er.

---

Evtl handelt es sich auch um einen [Spezialfall](http://brausch.org/home/homonyme/index.html)

> zusammengesetzter Homographen / Homonyme (Staubecken [Stau-becken, Staub-ecken])

aber das soll jeder für sich entscheiden ^^.

---

Nach einer Liste aller möglichen Wörter die so gebildet werden ist ambitioniert ^^. Es sind einfach zu viele. Vor allem, da du Wörter wie Mauer + er -> Maurer darunter zählst.

---

Ganz allgemein erinnert mich das Ganze allerdings vor allem an Bilderrätsel, bzw. die bekannten Rebus-Rätsel. Allerdings sind diese [graphisch dargestellt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9CFgUWd2Kc).

Comment: *Homophon* ist ein wichtiges Stichwort.

Answer (score -1):

### Das sind Paronomasien.

Eine [Paronomasie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronomasie) kann eine rhetorische Figur, aber auch ein Wortspiel sein, in deinem Fall handelt es sich um Wortspiele.

Das Wesen einer Paronomasie besteht darin, zwei Wörter mit ähnlichem Klang gleichzusetzen, die weder semantisch noch etymologisch zusammengehören.

Auf der [Wikipedia-Seite über Wortspiele](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortspiel) findet man auch dieses schöne Bild, dass hier recht gut dazu passt:

[image: A.B. Hörgeräte]
*<sup>Urheber des Bildes: Wikipedia-User "Alter Fritz"</sup>*

Comment: Eine Paranomasie könnte allenfalls die Beziehung zwischen dem eigenständigen Wort und dem ähnlich lautenden Wortbestandteil bezeichnen, als z.B. zwischen _Essen_ und _-essin_ (aus _Prinzessin)._ Wörter wie _Prinzessin,_ um deren Bezeichnung es hier geht, sind hingegen keine Paranomasien. Richtige Paranomasien sind Ausdrücke wie _Eile mit Weile_ oder _wer rastet, rostet._